# Phonegap android takes long to detect click event

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

There are many articles on removing click delay in mobile apps. Fastclick focuses on issue: "mobile browsers will wait approximately 300ms from the time that you tap the button to fire the click event."

But my query is bit different my android mobile application developed in eclipse is taking too long to enable click event (i.e 1st time the app loads click events are not fired for really long time and once the click event occurs for the 1st time, subsequent click events are much faster). I have only tested it on emulator have not tested yet on real device.

How can I remove that delay?

Here is my html page:

```
    <head>

    <title>First App</title>
    <style> 
    .table {
        border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
        background: #dddddd;
        width: 90px;
        height: 90px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 90px;
        position:absolute;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var areaIdvalue=1;
        var layoutIdvalue=1;

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady()
        {
            loadLayot();
            loadAreaButton();
            loadTableData();
        }

        function loadTableData()
        {
            $('.table1').html('');
            var param = "{'areaId':" + areaIdvalue + ",'layoutId':" + layoutIdvalue + "}";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",

                url: "http://192.168.0.70:81/MobileService.asmx/GetTables",
                data: param,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                success: function (msg) {
                    var Tabels = msg.d;
                    $.each(Tabels, function(index, table) {
                    var tabel_data='<div class="table"';
                    tabel_data +=' style="top:'+ table.PointY +'px;';
                    tabel_data +='left:'+table.PointX+'px;"';

                    tabel_data +=" ' >"+table.TableName +"</div>";
                    $('.table1').append(tabel_data);
                });
                $(".table").on("tap",function(){
                    window.location = "AddItems.html";
                });

                },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('error');
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }


        function loadLayot(){
            var param = "{'areaId':" + areaIdvalue + "}";
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url :"http://192.168.0.70:81/MobileService.asmx/FetchLayout",
                dataType:"json",
                data: param,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                success : function (msg) {

                    var Tabels = msg.d;
                    $.each(Tabels, function(index, table) {
                    var div_data="<option value="+table.LayoutId+">"+table.LayoutName+"</option>";
                    //alert(div_data);
                    $(div_data).appendTo('#Layout');   
                    $('#Layout').selectmenu('refresh');
                    });

                    $('#pageOne').on("change", '#Layout', function() {
                    layoutIdvalue=$('#Layout').val();
                    loadTableData();
                    });
                },
                error : function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('error');
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }

        function loadAreaButton(){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url :"http://192.168.0.70:81/MobileService.asmx/FetchArea",
                dataType:"json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                success : function (msg) {

                    var Tabels = msg.d;
                    $.each(Tabels, function(index, table) {
                    var div_data='<button class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline" value='+table.AreaId+'>'+table.AreaName+'</button>';
                    $(div_data).appendTo('#areadiv');  
                    $(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
                    areaIdvalue=$(this).attr('value');
                    loadTableData();
                    return false;
                    }); 

                });
                },
                error : function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('error');
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }

        function callAnothePage()
         {
            //window.location = "AddItems.html";
            $.mobile.changePage( "#pagetwo", { transition: "slidefade"} );
         }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page"  id="pageOne">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                <h1>Swift Retail</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                <div id="areadiv"></div>
                <fieldset class="ui-field-contain">
                    <label for="Layout">Select Layout</label>

                    <select id="Layout" >

                    </select>
                </fieldset>
                <div class="table1" style="position: absolute; display: block; width:100%; height:100%"; ></div>
            </div>

            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

            </div>
        </div> 
            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            </div>
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Strange issue. You can give "tap" event a try, though.

Comment: I tried with tap event also. Its the same

Comment: I have also noticed a similar problems with the emulator. The click event does not fire properly and gets stuck. Need to hit the click twice for firing, and then the event fires twice. Sometimes the click runs without any problems.

Comment: But in my case it looks like the 1st click event takes around 1 min to fire, then subsequent event are faster.

Comment: I know emulators are slow, can it be this slow?

Comment: @MysticMagic I have update my question with html page content. Please take a look. Anything wrong in my page which is slowing down the click event?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your app is lagging. Because javascript being single threaded and all, if you have a heavy enough code sometimes the UI & other events would get blocked. It doesn't take a minute to respond, it takes a minute to process the code then when it's finally free it would process the click.

**Q: How to make sure this is the case?**

**A:** Comment the 3 functions you are calling in `onDeviceReady` and just create a simple button that fires an alert or console log. Then run it on the same device/emulator.
If it works correctly, then hyg, this is your problem, you are running very inefficient code.

**Q: It's working but how to fix the efficiency problem?**

**A:** You are trying to run about 3 loops in the "same time" Do you really need to do that? How big are they? can they get smaller? Can you load sum and maybe do the others later? Maybe display a loading indicator until they are done?

**Q: That didn't fix it, what now?**

**A:** Well I can't think of anything else that might cause that, we will need more info, but you should try to run it on a real device possibly with a different android version.